# WCF + NUnit: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am currently struggling with a very unusual behavior with WCF.

I created a REST endpoint to use with my application, manually tested it out using curl and everything seems to be fine, until I tried to write NUnit tests for it.

The content of my test is basically creating a HttpWebRequest and hit it on my api. Whenever I run the test I get the following error

```
UnsupportedMediaType Cannot process the message because the content type
'application/json;charset=utf-8;' was not the expected type 'text/xml; 
charset=utf-8'.
```

I have searched for answers, almost all of them is related to mis-configured service, however that cant be the case since a curl request will work.
None explains how come the endpoint only fails with this setup.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The configuration might help to find the problem anyway. Could you share it?

Comment: is there a specific item you are looking for? The code is kind of confidential so best I can do is describe it. Basically I created a service which handles the said endpoint, and configed it in web.config.

Comment: Have you set `[WebInvoke(..., RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ...)]`?

Comment: @AlexK you mean on the endpoint itself? I haven't set the formats explicitly, I can give it a try, but why is it that when I use a command line based request it doesn't give an error?

Answer (score 0):

When you send the request you need to specify the type of content.  Try this -

```
HttpWebRequest request = ...
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
```

Also make sure that you are sending XML and **not** JSON content.

Comment: Thanks, but it kind of defeats the purpose if I set it to xml, sorry I didn't mention that this endpoint is used for a web app that relies on JSON so I have to test it with JSON. Thanks anyway though